# Can't find an object in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, class, object

I'm trying to find an object in an array list that's in another class by using the name of the object.

```
private void listParticipant() {
    System.out.print("Put in name of participant to see if currently registered: ");
    String name = readString(); 

    for (Team team : teamList) {
        if (team.hasParticipantWithName(name)) {
            System.out.println("Participant is registered.");
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Participant does not exist.");
}
```

But even though I know the list contains the name I'm putting in, it returns "participant does not exist".

This is the method in the team-class I'm using to find the name:

```
public boolean hasParticipantWithName(String name) {
    for (Participant part : participantList) {
        if (name.equals(part.getFullName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is my `getFullName` method in another class, that contains the constructor for participants.

```
public String getFullName(){
    String capitalizedLastName = lastName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+lastName.substring(1);
    String capitalizedFirstName = firstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+firstName.substring(1);
    return (capitalizedFirstName + " " +  capitalizedLastName);
}
```

The objects are added using constructor

```
public Participant(String firstName, String lastName, int id)
```

and input is then for example "john smith" and "John Smith"

My read string is

```
    private String readString() {
    return keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.. I've tried calling name by lowercase and uppercase first characters, but the method returns "does not exist" on everything. Any ideas? :)

Comment: with just the given code it´s pretty impossibl to tell (though i´m guessing `Object#equals` didn´t get overriden). You might want to include a MCVE in order for us to be able to reproduce that behaviour and be able to respond with an answer.

Comment: Please, give an input example..

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the name searched? and the `readString` method as well

Comment: Clearly need a [mcve] or at least the name and Team values

Comment: Stop downvoting the question. Probably, he is for the first time  on this forum.

Comment: @user7379898 We need the example input in order to see what you're doing wrong. At first glance your code looks fine.

Comment: The objects are added using constructor
public Participant(String firstName, String lastName, int id)
and input is then  for example "john smith"

Comment: `John Smith` should be the input and then it will be fine. You are comparing `john smith` with `John Smith` which will return false.

Comment: It doesn't work with either lowercase or uppercase as the first letters or the names..

Comment: Because you always end up with lowercase. `keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase()`. use equalsIgnoreCase (something like that ^^) to compare with the fullname

Comment: I would encourage you to learn to debug this yourself. If A does not equal B but you're convinced they are equal then why don't you print out the values of A and B just before the comparison? Maybe they're not what you expected them to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from your Scanner with this line :

```
return keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

And are getting the full name from

```
public String getFullName(){
    String capitalizedLastName = lastName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+lastName.substring(1);
    String capitalizedFirstName = firstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+firstName.substring(1);
    return (capitalizedFirstName + " " +  capitalizedLastName);
}
```

On one side you for the input to be lowercase, on the other side you force the full name to Have uppercase in first character. This will never be equals.

You can

- call `String.toLowerCase()` on `getFullName()` result since the input is already in lowercase both will match,
- use `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)` to ignore the case on both values

Note : The last one is safer because you don't need to bother to set yourself a specific case (lower or upper), it will be done in the method.